# Accessing array from props is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In `App.js` I have a component into which I pass some props:

```
<Populated
      addressParts={this.state.info}
 />
```

`this.state.info` is an object which contains other objects:

```
title: 'blahblahblah'
details: Array(3)
```

...and so on...

`details` has the following fields:

```
name: 'this is a question'
levelOfDifficulty: 100000
```

...and so on...

My code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'

class Populated extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <h1>{this.props.addressParts.title}</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default Populated
```

However, even if I try to console.log this.props.addressParts.details[0].name, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.addressParts.details[0]')
```

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to map the props to an initial state somehow?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `info` being fetched asynchronously?

Comment: @Max yes, it's being fetched and set in a separate handler function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing the props down correctly, you are getting the error because the component renders and tries to access `this.props.addressParts.details[0]` before the data has fetched. To avoid throwing an error, you can put this at the very top of the render method of the component that is causing the error:

```
if (!this.props.addressParts) return null;
```

Once the data is fetched and the props are updated the component will rerender.

You can also use lodash `_.get(this.props, 'addressParts.details[0]')` which will return undefined instead of throwing an error if `this.props.addressParts` is undefined.

Comment: do you know, how to put render() inside a condition?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the props in the first render call, because you are setting the state after you asynchronously fetching the data.

You could do a [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#___gatsby), either inside the `Populated` component or inside `App` component.

Here is a running snippet with your code, note that you must initiate the `info` to null so the current condition i did will work. you can do it in other ways and other conditions as well, this is just one of them.

```js
class Populated extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { addressParts } = this.props || {}; // just in case you want do defualt to an empty object
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{addressParts.title}</h1>
        <h2>{addressParts.details.name}</h2>
        <h3>{addressParts.details.levelOfDifficulty}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // you must initilize info to null so the current condition will work
      info: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // just mimic an async fetch here
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        info: {
          title: 'im here',
          details: {
            name: 'this is a question',
            levelOfDifficulty: 100000
          }
        }
      })
    }, 1200);
  }

  render() {
    const { info } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          info ?
            <Populated addressParts={this.state.info} /> :
            <div>Loading data...</div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```